# Game of Thrones in Dublin

Tags: tours, dublin

I'm in Dublin today, and I would like to know if it's there's a way to visit the Game of Thrones Tv show locations without pay for the tour (70EUR). That is possible to make the GoT tour by myself? And if yes, is a good choice to do that?

Comment: Are you after the stock footage? Or the sound stages and sets?  All of the stock footage locations are accessible by private car, rail, and so on.

Comment: I would like an alternative tour since the official tour are not available on the dates that I'll stay in Dublin.

Comment: No problem, people have been touring the stock footage locations for years, even centuries before Game of Thrones was invented.  You just go...

Answer (score 3):

The Dublin Winterfell tour is €55. They give out free cloaks and you even get to meet the real direwolves from seasons 1 and 2. See www.gameofthronestours.com.