# Can any of the Game of Thrones Castles in Ireland be Visited?

Tags: ireland, architecture, pilgrimages

Westeros is a fictional locale in the popular 'Game of Thrones' series. Its stock footage for some castles is filmed in the Republic of Ireland.

I would like to travel to Westeros for my next vacation, and I am wondering if any of the historically important places are open for tourists. In particular, I would be interested in finding out whether the ruins of Winterfell are accessible, and if so, whether I can get a guided tour there.

Also, I wonder if it is possible to stay overnight in any of those places, for instance, do they offer rooms now in the Twins or in the Eyrie?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a fictional show not travel. i'm assuming it's a joke, if you're interested in visiting the sets and/or filming locations for these fictional castles please edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: IIRC, "westeros" is Ireland, and several of the castle's/ruins shot are actual places in Ireland that one can visit...

Comment: Editing title and adding into paragraph.  Attempting to salvage a well-intended question.

Comment: Guys I think you have missed what was a joke ...

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45491/game-of-thrones-in-dublin  and see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45538/where-is-exactly-the-place-of-winterfell-from-game-of-thrones

Comment: i retracted my close vote. I still think it was a joke or outright trolling, but it's answerable now.

Comment: @SpaceDog, well done. It's on topic.  Now we have to decide if it's a duplicate or not. :)

Comment: If it's a troll, then they are gong to get a very sensible and factual answer, which a troll will find hugely disappointing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Game of Thrones is filmed in various places worldwide, not just Ireland. This [map](http://www.lawrenceofmorocco.com/news/game-of-thrones) gives you a good breakdown.

Many of the castles and other locations are actually filmed in several different locations combined with computer graphics, so don't expect to be able to find something exactly like what you see in the show.

In Ireland there are two castles that stand-in for Winterfell and you can tour them with [Game of Thrones](http://www.gameofthronestours.com/) tours as mentioned in the answer to this question: [Game of Thrones in Dublin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45491/game-of-thrones-in-dublin). For Castle Ward you cannot stay in the castle, but you can stay [nearby](http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/castle-ward/places-to-stay/) and there's are GoT themed [activities and tours](http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/wra-1359056442094/). The other place used is [Carncastle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carncastle), but it's more a place than a castle and appears to have been used for scenery and other establishing shots.

[Doune Castle](http://www.historic-scotland.gov.uk/propertyresults/propertyoverview.htm?PropID=PL_092) is Scotland was used as Winterfell in the pilot, you can tour that but not stay there.

The twins appear to be filmed in [Moneyglass Estate, County Antrim](http://www.ireland.com/en-gb/articles/game-of-thrones-locations/) but I think they're largely computer generated since I can find nothing that looks like them.

The other place on the map in Ireland that is used for castle filming is [Magheramorne Quarry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magheramorne), standing in for Castle Black and Hardholme. However this is a constructed set and not a real castle (although that page says they've built a fair amount of stuff). I can't find tours there (since it's an active filming site I'm not sure there would be) and you certainly can't sleep there.

The Eyrie is inspired by monasteries in [Metora](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/03/meteora-travel_n_5537198.html) in Greece. You can visit them but it doesn't appear you can stay in them.

As far as I can see there's no way to stay in anything remotely like a castle from the series. The closest would be places such as Morocco or Dubrovnik in Croatia which is where a lot of Kings Landing has been filmed. I'd imagine you could find somewhere in one of those places that would be the closest you can actually get.

There are many castles which might provoke the same sort of feeling and experience which you can stay in (see this [collection](https://www.pinterest.com/kiwicollection/hotel-stays-inspired-by-game-of-thrones/) on Pinterest for a start). But no way to stay in an actual castle from the series -- primarily because they're fictional places cleverly created from real world places, purpose built sets and computer graphics.

Comment: There is also a Google Maps version showing the locations. Might be useful for travel planning: https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zfTw8vt9xHfE.k2q98YGSbbis

Answer (score 2):

The Causeway Coast and Glens Borough Council has detailed information on their website:

http://www.visitcausewaycoastandglens.com/Game-Of-Thrones-A140
http://www.visitcausewaycoastandglens.com/Portals/0/GameOfThrones/GoTFilmingMap.pdf

Comment: Would you expand on the two commercial links you have provided? A good answer needs to persist by relying upon commercial links as incidental information only.  The OP wanted to know if it's possible to stay overnight and that needs to be part of your answer.  Thanks.